# Why this exception running my Spring Batch application? java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

I am working on a Spring Batch application.

I note the following points:

- At the moment Spring Batch is using the embedded H2 database that maybe it not ensure important performance (but I am not sure about this could be the cause of my problem). Anyway I will switch to MySql.
- My batch business logic doesn't read\write on DB (the reader call external APIs to retrieve data, the processor process these data in order to have the correct format and finnally the writer call other external APIs in order to persist these data into another destination system). So the DB should be used only by Spring Batch itself to take track of the step.

The problem is the following one: sometimes I obtain this exception:

```
Exception in thread "taskExecutor-8" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.update(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:378)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:96)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265)
    ... 23 more
```

What exactly mean? Why am I obtaining it?

The only database configuration found in my project are defined into the **application.properties** file:

```
#Batch Configuration
spring.batch.initialize-schema=NEVER
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

#Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:springbatch;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

#Liquibase Configuration
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog.xml
```

What could be the cause of this exception? Can I change some settings in order to solve this problem? Switching to MySql databse instead H2 can be a possible solution or it is an unrelated problem?

Comment: It looks that the Hikari pool is closed prematurely, ie something is trying to get a connection after the pool has been closed. I can't see from what you shared what could be the root cause, but if you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue I can try to help.